# jQuery UI Drop Anywhere on Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a page which contains a table. I want the user to be able to drag from one place to anywhere on the table. Drop does not seem to be fired.

JSFiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/netroworx/Kk9MX/

Javascript:

```
$('#dragSource').draggable();

$('#dropTable').droppable({
    drop: function() { alert('drop'); }
});
```

Html:

```
<p>Drop SOURCE anywhere on table</p>


<table id="dropTable" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Name</th><th>Description</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Name1</td><td>Description1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Name2</td><td>Description2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Name3</td><td>Description3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Name4</td><td>Description4</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div id="dragSource">SOURCE</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the `droppable` is not working on `table` if you surround the `table` with a `div` then it works

Check [**Fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mayekarsaurabh/Kk9MX/1/)